# Upload a profile pic with Reactjs and Nodejs to MongoDb

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am trying to let the user update their profile with their own avatar but for some reason, it doesn't work. I am sending a FormData from the front-end and catch it with nodeJs before storing it to MongoDB. user has 3 options to update: name, about, avatar. Whenever I try to update the name and about it works just fine but when I am uploading an avatar I get a 500 error. Can you guys take a look? FYI I am a begginer.
Here is my code:

***FRONT-END***

```
  const handleFileInputChange = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    previewFile(file);
    setUser({
      ...user,
      avatar: file,
    });
  };

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('name', user.name);
    formData.append('about', user.about);
    formData.append('avatar', user.avatar);

    editUserProfile(formData); // external axios.patch f.

  };


  const editUserProfile = async (formData) => {
    try {
      await axios.patch('api/v1/users/me', formData, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
        },
      });

      dispatch({
        type: EDIT_USER,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };



      <form onSubmit={onSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
        <input
          // accept="image/*"
          accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg"
          type="file"
          name="avatar"
          // value={fileInputState}
          onChange={handleFileInputChange}
          style={{ display: 'none' }}
          id="icon-button-file"
        />
...
```

***BACK-END***

```
router.patch('api/v1/users/me', protect, upload.single('avatar'), getMe, editUser = async (req, res) => {

try {

  const { name, about } = req.body;


  const profileFileds = {};
  if (name) profileFileds.name = name;
  if (about) profileFileds.about = about;
  if (req.file) profileFileds.avatar = req.file.filename;

  const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, profileFileds, {
    new: true,
    runValidators: true,
  });

  if (!user) {
    return next(
      new custom error...
    );
  }

  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: {
      user,
    },
  });
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err) error 400 ...
}


}););
```

Sorry guys if it's a long code and I really appreciate it, I am struggling 2 days now and can't figure it out

***//MULTER CONFIG just in case but it shouldn't be a problem with it***

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '/images');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, uuidv4() + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  },
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  const allowedFileTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png'];
  if (allowedFileTypes.includes(file.mimetype)) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 2,
  },
  fileFilter: fileFilter,
});
```

Comment: What type of error does the 500 gives you? Also, with the current code, you're storing the file on disk and not on MongoDB. You code seems valid at first glance.